# how do i use reflection to find the class member name for an ArrayLIst that is used in the class, example?

Tags: java, android, reflection, inner-classes

how can i use reflection to determine which variable was passed into a method?

example

```
public class ExampleClass {

  // class member variables
  ArrayList<String> strArrayOne;
  ArrayLIst<String> strArrayTwo;

  //constructor
  public ExampleClass()[
    strArrayOne = new ArrayList<String>();
    strArrayTwo = new ArrayList<String>();
  } 

   // create instance of nested class passing in the required ArrayList in constructor
   NestedInnerClass testInstance = new NestedInnerClass(strArrayOne);

  // nested inner class
  public class NestedInnerClass{

    // class member variable
    ArrayList<String> memberArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    // constructor
    public NestedInnerClass(ArrayList<String> inputArray){
      memberArray = inputArray;

      // put code here to determine with reflection which of the
      // two outer class variables is being passed in strArrayOne or strArrayTwo?
    }

  } // end nested inner class

} // end outer class
```

Comment: why reflection? `inputArray == strArrayOne` should be enough

Comment: Moreover, why not use the actual member variable within the inner class methods?

Comment: these are good questions, i guess that there are better tools for this job than reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need reflection to do that. It's enough to check for equality of the passed array and enclosing class's fields:

```
if (Arrays.equals(inputArray, ExampleClass.this.strArrayOne)) {
  // first one has been passed
}

if (Arrays.equals(inputArray, ExampleClass.this.strArrayTwo)) {
  // second one has been passed
}
```